# class hiddenSpellError in java script

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch

I am leaning sencha touch and I am following a dzone tutorial. I could not understand this line of code

```
<script class="hiddenSpellError"><!--mce:0--></script>
```

Can any one please tell me what this code mean.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is most likely an error in their tutorial due to some generated code (perhaps syntax highlighting?). I would ignore it as it doesn't have any affect on Sencha Touch.